# Is there a counterpart of /dev/random and /dev/urandom in Windows NT systems?

Tags: random-number-generator

I am trying to implement a TRNG on Windows and among other entropy sources, I want to extract raw bytes from various kinds of CPU and process info.

As per my knowledge, BCryptGenRandom is a CRNG in the Windows API that uses this kind of noise to generate entropy. Do files like /dev/random exist on Windows and if so how can I directly access these files from my client code? I have read that it isn't as straightforward as in UNIX systems.

Comment: 1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Other_operating_systems                   2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913614/simulating-dev-random-on-windows

Comment: Welcome, we value true entropists. See www.reallyreallyrandom.com re. TRNGs.

Comment: On Linux systems, /dev/random and /dev/urandom source from the *same* entropy pool through the *same* generator. The old split was based on a misunderstanding of how CSPRNGs work, and reduced practical security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three of them:

1. [`RtlGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-rtlgenrandom) a.k.a. `SystemFunction036` in `advapi32.dll`.  This is the oldest one, and is hacky, but it does work and won't be going away any time soon.
2. [`CryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom), the older CryptoAPI in Windows.  Crypt32 is obsolete, but current versions will accept it though might be slow.
3. [`BCryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom), the BCrypt library added in Windows Vista, is the current most supported one.

`BCryptGenRandom` is the one I would recommend.

Windows does not have a pseudo-file like `/dev/urandom`.  The NT path `\Device\KsecDD` is the kernel driver behind these GenRandom functions, but accessing the generator is done via `DeviceIoControl` rather than direct read operations.

Comment: Is there any solid documentation for the working of BCryptGenRandom? I don't understand if it directly provides raw noise from the system environment or manipulates and conditions the entropy (health checks, mixing, hashing, etc.) to generate cryptographically secure random bitstreams.